# Which is the better strategy for copying a table, insert twice or bulk copy at the end?

Tags: sql

I have a table that goes through a bunch of steps, and then needs to clear itself out. I want to copy the values from this table to another before it is truncated. I won't go into the specifics, but there is a good reason for this.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. The two options I see are:

-Everytime I insert/update the first table, perform the same operation on the second table.

-Once the first time is finalized, before it is truncated, copy it all over to the second table.

Is either strategy better then the other in terms of performance? I don't have much SQL experience, so I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is much better in terms of performance (bulk insert), since your table will be empty before the operations starts then all you need to do is a `Insert - select *`
and it will insert all of ur records into the second table.

Answer (score 1):

Answering which strategy is better for performance is impossible without knowing your setup and where your bottlenecks are.  Data I/O? Log I/O? Log space?  Maintenance window length?  "Better for performance" can mean "as fast as possible" or it can mean "with as few resources as possible".  There is no generally applicable answer to your question as posed.

Some google breadcrumbs may help you out though:  your first table is called a 'staging table' and your second is an 'audit table'.  Lots of discussions exist about performance and design of those.  You are likely to find one that approximates your setup and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally go with option #1. When you insert it, do it twice. It makes things easier and you don't have to run a huge query later to duplicate it.